# What should be the voltage rating of bootstrap capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, bootstrap

BST_1P is the bootstrap capacitor connection pin for high-side gate driver of TAS6422. 
In the [*datasheet*](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tas6422-q1.pdf) it is suggested that, this capacitor should have minimum rated voltage of 16 V.
What is the factor deciding this rated voltage.
Consider the maximum supply voltage is 16 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boot-strap capacitor is switched from the output to either being at GVDD or GND.

In the datasheet, GVDD is specified to be 7V, but the maximum output is 14.4V.  So 16V is probably they lowest they could recommend, though it probably also needs to be a larger case size part to not lose to much capacity to Vbias if ceramic.

Halfway through this [page](http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridge_drivers/) there is a nice drawing of a bootstrap NMOS H-Bridge.